# How to align two windows side by side in nw.js?

Tags: javascript, nw.js

This is my code..

```
var height=window.screen.availHeight;
var width=window.screen.availWidth;
var scenarioId = selectedScenarioIds[0];
var url ='url'+scenarioId;
width=(width/2);
if (typeof process == "object") {                               
     nw.Window.open(url, {
         position: 'center',
         width: width,
         height: height,
         focus: true
    }); 
 }
scenarioId = selectedScenarioIds[1];
var url ='url'+scenarioId;
if (typeof process == "object") {
    nw.Window.open(url, {
        position: 'center',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        focus: true
                });
    }
```

what i am trying to do is open two windows for comparison . The above code is working but the two windows are opening one behind another but i want it open one beside another .. any way to achieve this is nw.js ?
Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've got them both centered! Why don't you set **win.x** and **win.y** properties as required so that they will be positioned side by side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change positions of windows as [@Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6481523/coder) said. You can do it via `nw.Window.open` third argument used as callback function to manipulate opened window.

```
var width = window.screen.availWidth;
var halfWidth = width / 2 - 16; // Tested on Windows 8. Width of side borders: 8px.
var height = window.screen.availHeight;
var scenarioId = selectedScenarioIds[0];
var url ='url'+scenarioId;
if (typeof process == "object") {
    nw.Window.open(url, {
        position: 'center',
        width: halfWidth,
        height: height,
        focus: true
    }, function(win) {
        win.moveTo(0, 0);
    });
}
scenarioId = selectedScenarioIds[1];
url ='url'+scenarioId;
if (typeof process == "object") {
    nw.Window.open(url, {
        position: 'center',
        width: halfWidth,
        height: height,
        focus: true
    }, function(win) {
        win.moveTo(width, 0);
    });
}
```

Tested on Windows 8.1 where width of window borders is `8px` on both sided, so it must be subtracted from `window.screen.availWidth / 2`.

To successfully set positions of windows, their URLs must respond.